# Could not able to run selenium scripts on Firefox 50.1.0 with selenium 3.3.1

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Recently I have migrated my automation scripts from selenium 2.53 to 3.3.1 version, and we could not able to run scripts in Firefox version due to below exception. i m using **Firefox 50.1.0** and gecko v0.15.0

```
Exception in: TS_Testorg.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: Use gecko driver v01.15 and alsoo latest FireFox browser

Comment: You have to update your firefox browser version above >= 52

Comment: @acikojevic Probably, how to solve that error. Which is not going to be easy considering that he posted no code though.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide firefox binary location. One way of doing it is by the below code -

```
    FirefoxOptions ffOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //Location where Firefox is installed

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("moz:firefoxOptions", options);

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

More info here - http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Also are you using all the latest versions?